# For each loop through DayOfWeek enum to start on Monday?

Tags: c#, enums, dayofweek

I am iterating through the DayOfWeek Enum like this :

```
foreach (DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
{
 // Add stuff to a list 
}
```

And my problem is that I would like my enum to start by Monday instead of Sunday.

I tried to do :

```
CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
```

But the foreach loop still started with Sunday.

How can I do this ?

My last idea would be to reorder my resulting list to the order of day I want 
but that would mean more iterations.

Thanks !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That isn't possible, purely because setting the culture doesn't change the fact that the `DayOfWeek` `enum` is defined as such:

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

You can, however, skip the first entry and add it later.. perhaps like this:

```
foreach (DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
                              .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
                              .ToList()
                              .Skip(1)) {
    list.Add(day.ToString());
}
list.Add(DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString());
```

Answer (score 9):

A single call to `OrderBy` can order them as desired.  It's not possible to change the order of the call to `Enum.GetValues`.

```
var daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
    .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
    .OrderBy(day => day < DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a *for* loop and the modulo (%) operator :

```
DayOfWeek day;
for( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
{
    day = (DayOfWeek) ((i + 1) % 7);
    // Add stuff to a list
}
```

If you want to use this loop to shift another enum, you can always replace the number 7 with a variable initialized like this :

```
int length = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Length;
```

You could even write a method to shift any enum, assuming that this enum has all the values between *0, 1, ..., n* :

```
static IEnumerable<TEnum> Shift<TEnum>(int offset) where TEnum : struct
{
    int length = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Length;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )
    {
        yield return (TEnum) (object) ((i + offset) % length);
    }
}
```

Comment: `day = (DayOfWeek)(i);` is suffice if you change for loop to `i<=7`.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a custom `IComparer<DayOfWeek>`:

```
public class DayOfWeekComparer : IComparer<DayOfWeek> {
    public int Compare(DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y) {
        return ModifyDayOfWeek(x).CompareTo(ModifyDayOfWeek(y));
    }

    private static int ModifyDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek x) {
        // redefine Sunday so it appears at the end of the ordering
        return x == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : (int)x;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
foreach(DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
                             .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
                             .OrderBy(x => x, new DayOfWeekComparer())) {
    // will see Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}
```

Edit to add:

Actually, even *that* is too complicated, as pretty as it is. Why don't you just put

```
static IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> DaysOfWeek {
    get {
        yield return DayOfWeek.Monday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Friday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        yield return DayOfWeek.Sunday;
   }
}
```

somewhere, anywhere, and just be done with it! [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Answer (score 0):

[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) returns elements which are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (see *Remarks* on MSDN). `DayOfWeek` enumeration defined this way:

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

As you can see, `Monday` defined as `1` and `Sunday` defined as `0`. So, you can't force `Enum.GetValues` method to return `Monday` before `Sunday`.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
foreach (DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
                      .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
                      .ToList()
                      .Skip(1).Union(new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Sunday}))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```